# Proper way to break apart a file with Mercurial/general version control?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I currently have a source file with two classes in it. I'd like to move one of them into a separate file. Is there any way to do this in a way similar to "hg mv" where Mercurial realizes the relationship between the new file and the part of the old file? Or does it have to look to Mercurial like a big chunk of one file was deleted and a brand new file was created? Is there some other best-practice I should be following here?

I will be very impressed if this kind of tracking actually exists, but it wouldn't be the first time Mercurial has pleasantly surprised me.

Comment: The upvoted answer (not the accepted one) might help a bit.

Comment: Yep, that answers my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do it via copy (**hg copy**) command. Just create a copy, change each copy and commit.

Comment: Upvote and accept for brevity :) And, of course, for being the correct answer in many ways: while it's clear from the other question that there is no real official way to do this, and it perfectly address merging, it's a heck of a lot better than creating a new file and copying and pasting, especially for functions like `hg blame`.